# How to make a relation in laravel with multiple pivot tables?

Tags: php, laravel

I got a tables:

- users (id, name, surname)
- weddings (id, ...)
- wedding_user (id, wedding_id, user_id, role_id)
- wedding_user_permission (wedding_user_id, permission_id)

And I want to make a relation between Wedding and WeddingUser model (Wedding has many WeddingUser, WeddingUser belongs to Wedding).

Actually, if I'll ignore laravel relations, model will be:

```
//Wedding Model 

public function users()
    {
        $users = WeddingUser::where('wedding_id', $this->id)->get();
        return $users;
    }
```

But I need to do this with the laravel relations.

I tried this:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\Models\WeddingUser',
            'wedding_user',
            'user_id'
        );
    }
```

But it throws an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'wedding_user' (SQL: select `wedding_user`.*, `wedding_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `wedding_user`.`wedding_user_id` as `pivot_wedding_user_id` from `wedding_user` inner join `wedding_user` on `wedding_user`.`id` = `wedding_user`.`wedding_user_id` where `wedding_user`.`user_id` in (1))
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: What you're looking for is the [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship.

Comment: @snh, not sure. Can you show any example in this case?